# Android - Appsflyer AD_ID permission error in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, appsflyer-android-sdk

I have an application already in Google Play Console. I just added Appsflyer SDK to my application by using [this official guide](https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/install-android-sdk) and integrated it by using [this official guide](https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/integrate-android-sdk).

I just added those lines to my `Application` class:

```
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().init("MY DEV KEY", null, this)
            AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().start(this, "MY DEV KEY", object : AppsFlyerRequestListener {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                    //Log.d("APPSFLYER", "Launch sent successfully")
                }

                override fun onError(errorCode: Int, errorDesc: String) {
                    /*
                    Log.d("APPSFLYER", "Launch failed to be sent:\n" +
                            "Error code: " + errorCode + "\n"
                            + "Error description: " + errorDesc)

                     */
                }
            })
```

Also added those lines to Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove"/>
...

<application
        tools:replace="android:fullBackupContent"
...
</application>
```

Lastly to gradle:

```
//AppsFlyer
    implementation "com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.12.2"
```

My Target SDK is 34.

It works perfectly. I see that organic data comes to Appsflyer dashboard.

But when I try to submit my application to Google Play Console, I see that error:

[image]

I already set up the Advertising ID section in Play Console because of my Firebase Crashlytics implementation:

[image]

As you see, in this section, it says `Your manifest file includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission. This means your app declares the use of advertising ID. Answer 'yes' or remove this permission from your manifest.` but on first picture, it says `no`.

What am I missing? What is the solution for this ?

Comment: Notice that the warning from Google states that "A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.gms.permission.AD_ID permission". Do you have any other libraries that might be causing this?

Comment: @tomerpacific this error is occured only when I only add appsflyer sdk. I suspect about only this

Comment: @Wicaledon why do you remove the permission from the app while select "Yes" in the "Advertising ID" section in Play Console?

Comment: @VladGuriev sorry I didnt understand, I didn't remove it, I added this permission. if you mean `tools:node="remove"` line, I added because of explanation in https://dev.appsflyer.com/hc/docs/install-android-sdk#the-ad_id-permission

Comment: @Wicaledon but it is the removal. `tools:node="remove"` prevents a permission from being added to the final `Manifest`. Basically it means that there is no such permission in the app

Comment: @VladGuriev ok but why they say `When using SDK V6.8.0 and above, children apps targeting Android 13 (API 33) and above must prevent the permission from getting merged into their app by adding a revoke declaration to their Manifest:` ? shall I use lower than 6.8.0 ?

Comment: @Wicaledon is your app a children app?

Answer (score 1):

Please read carefully the condition "If your app participates in the Designed for Families program: " then consider the condition: "If using SDK V6.8.0 and above, you should Revoke the AD_ID permission.".

So if your app is not part of the "Designed for Families program" or "Children app". Please remove "tools:node="remove" in you Manifest and you will fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, we recommend updating the SDK to the latest version.

Our latest SDK version (v6.12.4) you can find [here](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001256006).

You declare that you are collecting Advertising Identifier in the screenshot.

It says:

> You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration

If you are revoking the permission, it means that you don't want to collect GAID, which contradicts what you've declared.

For a quick sanity test, try aligning the privacy declaration with the permissions in the Manifest. Then, check to see if the error has been resolved.